# Error Installing web3js for Ethereum / Unable to connect to github.com

Tags: web3js, javascript, quorum

I'm using npm to install web3js:

```
npm install web3
```

It eventually fails. Here is the output I get...

```
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: â ï¸  WARNING â ï¸ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.255.113]: errno=Connection timed out
npm ERR! github.com[1: 192.30.255.112]: errno=Connection timed out
```

Here is some version info:

```
uname -a

Linux bde2744830c3 4.1.12-103.7.1.el7uek.x86_64

npm --version 

5.5.1
```

I've scoured SO and other sites that have somewhat similar postings, but nothing that offers help. I've tried:

```
npm cache verify
```

To no avail.

Comment: Now it does install correctly web3@1.0.0-beta.26, perhaps it was an issue with github.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution is to type **sudo -i**
and then **sudo npm install web3**
It worked for me

Comment: You should never use sudo when using npm.
Install & use nvm instead.